# regex test alwayes returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#pincode").blur(function () {
    var pincode = $("#pincode").val().trim();
    var pattern = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
    if (pincode != "" && !IsPatternFormate(pincode, pattern)) {
        $("#pincode").addClass('invalidValidation');
        document.getElementById('pincode')
                .setCustomValidity('please enter data in proper formate');
    }
});

var IsPatternFormate = function (value, pattern) {    
    var match = pattern.test($(value));
    console.log(match);
}
```

i don't know why, match always return me false value.

Comment: Why do you pass "value" to `$()`? That makes absolutely no sense; it should just be `pattern.test(value);` And you need a `return` from the function.

Comment: Your function returns nothing and undefined is falsy

Comment: when you call `$(something)` you get jQuery array-like object, so when you pass it object to `test` function that need string parameter, really passed something like `"[object Object]"` so it always return _false_ for your pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var IsPatternFormate = function (value, pattern) {    
        if(pattern.test(value)){
         return true;
        }else{
         false;
         }

    }
```

Change your IsPatternFormate function

Comment: `test` function already return boolean, so `return pattern.test(value)` is enough

Comment: can i write as var IsPatternFormate = function (value, pattern) {    
       
         return pattern.test(value);
       
    }

Comment: @radhey_mishra yes that would be more precise